# Генератор случайных чисел в заданном диапазоне и количестве

Tags: php, случайные-числа

Я знаю, что есть функция в ПХП для генерации случайных чисел. mt_rand, например.
Но мне нужно слегка не это. Мне нужно, скажем 1000 случайных чисел в диапазоне (1-5. то бишь 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Таким образом, чтобы в итоге, после выполнения цикла, было равное количество.
То есть 200 раз число 1, 200 - 2, 200 - 3 итд, но в случайной последовательности. Чтобы я был уверен, что группы либо равны либо очень близки к этому. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Ежели не обращать внимание на распределение, то можно взять список из 1000 чисел и случайным образом удалять по одному (одно из 1000, одно из 999, одно из 998 и т.д.).

Comment: положить в массив по 200 раз эти числа а потом shuffle(); в чем проблема ? (или наоборот, положить 200 раз массив всех вариантов и опять-же перемешать)

Comment: @jackair, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

```
$arr = array();
$max_items = 1000; // Длина массива
$min_number = 0; // Любое число
$max_number = 20; // Генерация от min_number до этого числа
for($i = 0, $j = $min_number; $i < $max_items; $i++) {
    if ($j > $max_number)
      $j = $min_number;

$arr[] = $j;
$j++;       
}

shuffle($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: не, смысл в том, что 1000 это для примера. на практике числа будут на порядки больше!) и вообще это число динамическое

Comment: @jackair, поправил.

Answer (score 5):

Вот моя гибкая реализация вашего кода )
Распределит равномерно количество выпадов.

***$min*** //минимальное число
***$max*** //максимально число
***$sum*** //количество оборотов
***$eqv***  //распределяем количество совпадений на одно значение (+ приводим к целому числу)

```
function evenRand($min,$max,$sum){
    $eqv = floor($sum / (($max-$min)+1));
    $array = array();

    for($i=0;$i<$sum;$i++){
        $rand = mt_rand($min,$max);

        if($array[$rand] != $eqv){
            $array[$rand]+=1;

        } else {
            $sum+=1;
        }
    }
    echo $array[2];  // Для проверки. Выведет количество выпавших "2"
}

evenRand(1,5,1000); // = ровно 200 выпадов на каждое число
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Генерируешь массив от 1 до 5, и так 200 раз [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2, ... , 5]
2. Сортируешь его в случайном порядке